# MYSQLI SELECT Fatal error

Tags: php, mysqli

При попытке получить UUID выдает ошибку

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean in /var/www/www-root/data/www/hypecraft.ru/engine/modules/banlist/index.php:88 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/www-root/data/www/hypecraft.ru/engine/classes/templates.class.php(267): include() #1 [internal function]: dle_template->load_file(Array) #2 /var/www/www-root/data/www/hypecraft.ru/engine/classes/templates.class.php(654): preg_replace_callback('#\{include file...', Array, '

Вот код

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add_ban'])){
    if($usergroup == '1' || '2'){
$ban_name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["ban_name"]);
$ban_reason = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["ban_reason"]);
$time = time();
$time = date("Y-m-d G-i-s", $time);
if($mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['perm']) == "ban_perm"){
$ban_time = '0';
}else{
$ban_time = time();
$sutk = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["sutk"]);
$sutk = $sutk * 24 * 60 * 60;
$hour = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["hour"]);
$hour = $hour * 60 * 60;
$min = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["min"]);
$min = $min * 60;
$ban_time = $ban_time + $sutk + $hour + $min;
$ban_time = date("Y-m-d G-i-s", $ban_time);
};
/* return name of current default database */

$uuid = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM dle_users WHERE username='$ban_name'");
while($uuids = $uuid->fetch_array()){
$uuids1 = $uuids['uuid'];
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO $db_table (name, uuid, reason, admin, time, temptime) VALUES ('$ban_name', '$uuids1', '$ban_reason', '$username', '$time', '$ban_time')");
}

}else{
echo "Ошибка! У вас нет доступа!";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Возможно просто у вас нет данных из базы, до цикла проверьте не пустой ли $uuid

Comment: суть в том что я указываю ник у которого есть uuid. и выдает ошибку!

Comment: логику цикла поставьте в if(!empty($uuid)) { ...while(){}.....}

Comment: Добавил, все равно ошибка!

Comment: а вы хоть проверили что выводит $uuid ? var_dump() хоть сделайте, может она не пуста но и данных для перебора нет!!

Comment: выводит такую же ошибку!

Comment: $uuid = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM dle_users WHERE username='$username'");
while($uuids = $uuid->fetch_array()){
if(!empty($uuids['uuid'])) {
$uuids1 = $uuids['uuid'];
}else {
$uuids1 = 725725;
};
var_dump($uuids1);
}